# Moving or hiding the system bar

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, user-interface

I find that the system bar (containing the back, home, recent application, and status menu buttons) at the bottom of my android tablet often interferes with typing. Is there currently a method to reposition the bar to the top of the screen? The closest application I've found is Hidebar, but it only works on Honeycomb.

Answer (score 1):

may be you can use another home screen called "Launcher Pro" Free version.

In the setting there is an option to hide the system bar. you can try it out if you like the home screen. though i like it better than stock home screen.